# Python List Error not callable

Tags: python, list

```
import math

def getBestLoc(lst):
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        #bestLoc = (lst((len(lst)/2) + lst(len(lst)/2)-1))/2
        bestLoc = ((lst[len(lst)]//2) + (lst[len(lst)/2]-1)) // 2
    else:
        bestLoc = lst(len(lst)//2)
    sumOfDistances(lst, bestLoc)
    return bestLoc

def sumOfDistances(lst, bestLoc):
    total = 0
    for i in lst:
        total += math.abs(bestLoc - i)
    return total

def main():
    lst = [10, 15, 30, 200]
    lst.sort()
    print(lst)
    getBestLoc(lst)

main()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\storeLocation.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\storeLocation.py", line 30, in main
    getBestLoc(lst)
  File "C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\storeLocation.py", line 14, in getBestLoc
    bestLoc = ((lst[len(lst)]//2) + (lst[len(lst)/2]-1)) // 2
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know what I did wrong. It is saying, `IndexError: list index out of range`, I don't know what that means. It is my lab homework. Trying to figure this issue out. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to access an element of the list with `[]`, not to call it as a function with `()`. Replace:

```
bestLoc = ((lst(len(lst))/2) + (lst(len(lst)/2)-1)) / 2
```

with

```
bestLoc = ((lst[len(lst)]/2) + (lst[len(lst)/2]-1)) / 2
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't look carefully at the [] and (). Also, When I done that, I get this new error: `IndexError: list index out of range` I don't get how is this out of range.

Comment: Replace `lst[len(lst)]` with `lst[len(lst) - 1]` or (better) with `lst[-1]` to correctly get the last element.

Comment: Also, if using Python3, replace `/` with `//`, or you might get an error complaining about float.

Comment: `bestLoc = ((lst[-1]/2) + (lst[len(lst)/2]-1)) / 2
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float` I have no idea what is the means. I know what is Int and Float.

Comment: Read the comment above: replace `lst[len(lst)/2]` with `lst[len(lst)//2]`

Comment: I did that, check the post above. I edited it. Still giving me the `index out of range`

Comment: Nevermind I got it. `bestLoc = (lst[len(lst)//2] + (lst[(len(lst)//2)-1]) / 2)`

Answer (score 2):

accessing list element uses square bracket [] not ()

should be

```
((lst[len(lst)]/2) + (lst[len(lst)/2]-1)) / 2
```

same thing with the else: clause

Comment: Thanks! I didn't look carefully at the [] and (). Also, When I done that, I get this new error: `IndexError: list index out of range` I don't get how is this out of range.

Comment: `a = [1,2,3]`, `len(a)=3`, but last element of `a` is `a[2]`, so you have to do `a[len(a) - 1]` to get the last element

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to use `lst` as a function by using `lst(...)`. Try using square brackets `lst[...]`.

Answer (score 1):

What other posters have said.  Use square brackets `[]` instead of parentheses `()` to access list elements. eg. `lst[index]`  Also, you are attempting to access elements outside the list.

Don't use `lst[len(lst)]` - you automatically get an index out of bounds exception.
Instead, use `lst[len(lst)-1]`.

Also, don't use math.abs, that function doesn't exist in python.  Instead use math.fabs

Comment: Actually, you have `abs` in Python.

Comment: I don't quite understand `Don't use....` Which part in the code? I know I got the `index out of range`